# No Guile Development package found im compiling open-connect source code from git-hub

Tags: openconnect

```
*** Detecting GNU Guile...

checking for guile-snarf... /usr/bin/guile-snarf
checking for guild... /usr/bin/guild
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
configure: checking for guile 2.2
configure: checking for guile 2.0
configure: checking for guile 1.8
configure: error: 
No Guile development packages were found.

Please verify that you have Guile installed.  If you installed Guile
from a binary distribution, please verify that you have also installed
the development packages.  If you installed it yourself, you might need
to adjust your PKG_CONFIG_PATH; see the pkg-config man page for more.
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What is OpenConnect? What is the link to its repo?

Answer (score 0):

In synaptic package manager or through the terminal with "apt-get install", install guile and guile-dev. After the installation, you will have /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/guile-.pc file. Then all you need to do is to:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
```

and then configure or just go to the source directory and run:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig ./configure
```