# How to update PKG_CONFIG_PATH for Guile?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, make

While trying to install [chickadee](https://dthompson.us/projects/chickadee.html) on Ubuntu, I ran `./configure` inside the extracted folder and got errors as below:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes <>
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for guile... /usr/bin/guile
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
configure: checking for guile 3.0
configure: checking for guile 2.2
configure: error:
No Guile development packages were found.

Please verify that you have Guile installed. If you installed Guile
from a binary distribution, please verify that you have also installed
the development packages.  If you installed it yourself, you might need
to adjust your PKG_CONFIG_PATH; see the pkg-config man page for more.
```

I've already installed Guile-3.0.1 via `apt install`. I am able to see Guile inside `/usr/bin/`, but I'm not able to see Guile inside `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig` as mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199775/no-guile-development-package-found-im-compiling-open-connect-source-code-from-gi/1254328).

I also tried updating `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` with the values: `/usr/bin/pkg-config` and it did not work.

Here is the relevant log from `config.log` inside the chickadee folder:

```
~/Downloads/chickadee-0.5.0$ cat config.log | grep pkg
configure:2510: checking for pkg-config
configure:2528: found /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure:2540: result: /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure:2565: checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0
Package guile-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Package guile-2.2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
to adjust your PKG_CONFIG_PATH; see the pkg-config man page for more.
ac_cv_path_ac_pt_PKG_CONFIG=/usr/bin/pkg-config
PKG_CONFIG='/usr/bin/pkg-config'
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you installed only the application, and not the development libraries, asked for by configure. In your case, try :
`sudo apt-get install guile-3.0-dev`
What packages are available can be listed by :
`apt-cache search guile`

Comment: Search [on packages.ubuntu.com for files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=guile%20.pc) is useful too.

Comment: @oscar1919  it worked thanks!
there is next issue: 


`configure: error: required guile module not found: (gl)`

- I have installed OpenGL and tried again. But the issue persists..

Comment: @88dax I think you need guile opengl.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/guile-opengl/  Probably it is not packaged for ubuntu.  Not familiar on how to build or install this.

Comment: Yeah, I installed Guile OpenGL and during its installation, I'm facing the ```PKG_CONFIG_PATH``` issue again. I'm still trying to find a workaround.

Comment: Tried to help by posting additional answer.

Answer (score 2):

A library can use pkg-config to communicate build info to other libraries (location of libraries, compiler flags, ...).  This is stored in a .pc file.  If this .pc file is not stored in the default pkg-config search path, it is possible to extend the search path of pkg-config.
Find the .pc file yourself, suppose your library is called `guile-something`, then try e.g.
`sudo find / -name "guile*.pc"`
Assuming that the pc file is found in e.g. `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` this directory may be added to the pkg-config path by adding the line
`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`
either to `~/.bashrc`, then it will be set at every invocation of `bash`
or to `~/.profile`, then it will be set at every login
To list all the libraries currently seen by pkg-config, execute
`pkg-config --list-all`